# Strange runtime error when iterating over std::deque

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, runtime-error

Consider the following piece of code:

```
 1  typedef std::deque<int> mydeque_t;
 2  mydeque_t mydeque;
 3   
 4  mydeque_t::iterator start = mydeque.begin();
 5  
 6  for (int i = 0; i != 1000; ++i)
 7       mydeque.push_back(i);
 8  
 9  for (mydeque_t::iterator myint = start; myint != mydeque.end(); ++myint)
10     *myint += 1;
```

When executing it I always get a runtime error on line 10 (live example: http://ideone.com/juQAA). However when I change line 6 to `for (int i = 0; i != 100; ++i)` the code works fine.

The code would easily be fixed by moving the `start` definition (line 4) behind  the first for loop, but in my example I need it to stay before it. However even like this I think it should run fine, can anyone explain to me why it does not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a call to `push_back()`, all iterators are invalidated. From [`deque::push_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/push_back):

> Appends the given element value to the end of the container. 
>   **All iterators are invalidated**. No references are invalidated.

*Guess*: The code probably works fine with `100` and not `1000` as the internal storage of the deque did not have to be reallocated to accomodate the `100` elements resulting in the `begin()` iterator remaining valid.

Comment: If you really, really wanted your iterators to remain valid, you should consider using other containers with more friendly iterator semantics. A `std::list` is a more or less drop-in replacement for `std::deque` in this regard.